# How to get the controller of a form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Say I have several forms each with their own controller that look like this

```
 <div ng-controller="MyController1 as ctrl">
    <label>Some label </label>
</div>

<div ng-controller="MyController2 as ctrl">
    <label>Some label </label>
</div>
```

And I have a global controller, that gets the information about the form names. Now I want to find the controllers for each form. For instance, if in my global controller function, I get the name of the first form, how can I find out that its controller is MyController1? Is that even possible?

Comment: Smells like "use AngularJS factories".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Get Controller from Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995108/angular-get-controller-from-element)

Answer (score 1):

Calling a controller from another controller is possible. But, I believe the problem you're trying to solve is somewhere else: the architecture of your app.

Ideally, your app should 'react' to changes on the state. The state should be kept in a single place (also called 'single source of truth'), ie. a service. Then you share that service state with as many controllers as you need.

You can either update the service state directly from the controller, or by calling a method on the service itself.

Look at the example below. I hope that sheds some light.

Cheers!

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.service('MyService', function(){
  var self = this;
  self.state = {
    name: 'John'
  };
  
  self.changeNameFromService = function() {
    self.state.name = 'Peter';
  }
})
.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, MyService){
  $scope.state = MyService.state;
  
  $scope.changeName = function(){
    // update the state of the scope, which is shared with other controllers by storing the state in a service
    $scope.state.name = 'Mary';
  }
})
.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope, MyService){
  $scope.state = MyService.state;
  
  // call a method defined in service
  $scope.changeName = MyService.changeNameFromService;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    Ctrl1: {{state.name}}
    <button ng-click="changeName()">Change name!</button>
  </div>
  
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    Ctrl2: {{state.name}}
    <button ng-click="changeName()">Change name from service!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments and the sample code. I will have a look at it. But just to avoid any misunderstandings @JorgeObregon: i just want to get the name of the controller, I don't want to call it from another controller. Is there an easy way to do this?